# Genus of a complete bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

How do I prove that the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ has genus $\lceil (m−2)(n−2)/4 \rceil$?

I know that the genus of $K_n$ is $\lceil (n-3)(n−4)/12 \rceil$ but I cannot obtain the required proof.

Answer (score 1):

Proven in:

- Ringel, G. "Das Geschlecht des vollständiger Paaren Graphen." Abh. Math. Sem. Univ. Hamburg 28, 139-150, 1965.
- Harary, F. ***Graph Theory***, Reading, MA: Addison-Wesley, 1994, page 119.

Comment: 1. In Harary, F. Graph Theory, the result is only stated (and the easy lower bound explained).
2. Nice alternative proof in A. Bouchet, Orientable and nonorientable genus of the complete bipartite graph., Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series B 24.1 (1978): 24-33.